# pdflatex (file cmss10.t3): cannot open Type 1 font file for read

Tags: latex, fedora, pdflatex, beamer

I am trying to generate a pdf file from this sample beamer presentation file:

```
\begin{document}
\frame {
    \titlepage
}
\frame {
    \frametitle{Sample Page 1}
    \[\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - c}}{2a}\]
}
\frame{
    \frametitle{Sample Page 2}
    \framesubtitle{An Example of Lists}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item 1
        \item 2
        \item 3
    \end{itemize}
}
\frame{
    \frametitle{Paragraph Content}
    This is a paragraph.
}
\end{document}
```

I tried to generate a PDF file using pdflatex but it fails:

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file cmss10.t3): cannot open Type 1 font file for reading ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I downloaded the missing file and put it in the same directory where my tex file is and reran the pdflatex command, the error message is:

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ./cmss10.t3): Type3 fonts unsupported by pdfTeX
```

Can someone suggest me how to solve that issue ? By the way, I am using TexLive full scheme on Fedora 35.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A very nice duck found this link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/621447/unable-to-generate-a-pdf-on-fedora-35-pdftex-error-cannot-open-type-1-font-fi Can you check if this helps in your case?

Comment: Someone seems to have added the mpfonts.map which should be used only with dvips to updmap. Try in your document preamble `\pdfmapfile{-mpfonts.map}`  to remove the entries again.

Comment: if the local removal resolves the problem, then  `sudo updmap-sys --disable mpfonts.map` can probably be used to disable the map permanantly, but I'm on windows, so can't test that.